# Git rollback my commits

Tags: git, version-control

I commit my and push them to Git.
My colleagues commit their changes.
I commit more of my changes.

I have been told that my changes cannot be tested for
This release and have to go in the next release. I have to back out all my changes and only my changes. How can I do that?

I use tortoise when pushing or puling my changes into Git. I am using windows XP machine.

Yes, I pulled my colleagues work before pushing my commits.

I have to mention though that my changes were for completely different files. None of my colleagUes touched them.

It is just one branch, which is the integration branch.

Comment: You will probably need to post far more information about your setup in order to get a good response.

Comment: Yes, a bit vague. Did you pull and merge your colleagues' commits before trying to push your new ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why simply not using the `git revert` command ?

Comment: This is the proper way to do it when the commits have been pushed to a shared repo.

Comment: "I commit my and push them to Git." ... Sounds like it is the case to me.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say initial integrated Repo is I and when your commit is Y and later your collegues commit is C. So may be the line of development looks like this. And the file system is F at present.

```
          (F)    
I--Y--C1--C2
           ↑
          HEAD
```

And as you mentioned

> I have to mention though that my changes were for completely different
>   files. None of my colleagUes touched them.

So you could keep on doing reset HEAD~1 till you reach I, the commit before *you* made any changes. Say there are two commits after your commit. You could use this to reach commit I.

```
git reset HEAD~3
```

And as your files are preserved this may look like

```
          (F)    
I--Y--C1--C2
↑           
HEAD
```

Now you could just delete your files from the system and add the files of your collegues (to the index, its already there on FileSystem) and then do a commit. And now the dev line may look like without your changes.

```
    (F1) 
 I--C3
    ↑
   HEAD
```

This is not a recommended way. The recommended way to do it is using

```
 git revert HEAD^
```

Though I have never used it,so to cant tell.

EDIT: Another way of doing it.
Find the "SHA KEY" of the your commit "Y" and commit just before that "I". 
It can be done using

```
git log
```

Lets say the for Y key is: 7a2ab465aad23dc66a23ade897deb65a5bf9419d 
And for I key is:          906488ac2d5a8468d725351df80e3b0f6338c9be 
Make tags for both commits like

```
git tag Intercommit -a 906488ac2d5a8468d725351df80e3b0f6338c9be
git tag YourCommit -a  7a2ab465aad23dc66a23ade897deb65a5bf9419d
```

Checkout intercommit using

```
git checkout Intercommit
```

Then rebase the repo using

```
git rebase --onto HEAD YourCommit master
```

Now the line of dev will look like

```
I--C1--C2
       ↑
      HEAD
```

You can find more about rebasing and rewriting one commit on

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/user-manual.html#rewriting-one-commit

and

http://learn.github.com/p/rebasing.html